# Software to check if music file (approximately) contains segment of audio? (both mp3)

Tags: music, ubuntu, patternmatching

**TL;DR**: Is there an automated way to filter a list of files selecting the files that approximately contain another file?

Example:

Files to be tested (potentially hundreds):

```
my_file_1.mp3
my_file_2.mp3
my_file_3.mp3
my_file_4.mp3
my_file_5.mp3
my_file_6.mp3
```

Part of song:

```
piece_of_audio.mp3
```

Result of the program:

```
# Do your magic here!
my_file_2.mp3 contains piece_of_audio.mp3
my_file_3.mp3 contains piece_of_audio.mp3
my_file_4.mp3 contains piece_of_audio.mp3
```

I am no audio expert so I would like the software to be "flexible" in the way it searches for the "containing" relationship. In other words it should not do a byte by byte comparison of the file as in a "substring matching".

Comment: Are you looking for a file being embedded __as a file with any name__ or are you looking for a specific __audio__ _or music_ __segment__ being somewhere in the audio content. e.g. are you looking to detect sampled tracks, etc.

Comment: I'm looking to detect if a file appears somewhere in other file. The name of the files are not important. In principle there is one master file and a bunch of other files. Rephrasing the question: which of this bunch of files contain audio from master file?

Comment: Making it more human friendly: there is a radio show that plays a jingle on its start everytime. I have this jingle isolated (~10 seconds). I would like to scan dozen of files that may contain this jingle (thus they will contain an episode of the radio show).

Comment: I would say that you are looking to search a bunch of files to find out if/where/how many times an audio segment defined in another file appears.